# How to properly instantiate an empty pandas Series for "any" dtype in version 2.2.0?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas `2.2.0` raises a FutureWarning `Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated`.

While this sounds like a helper to avoid possible type casting issues, it's actually introducing a new problem if you want to initialize an empty Series and only later fill it, for example by copying over a bunch of records, or single elements. For example, the below raises a warning, and will raise an error in the future:

```
my_index = pd.Index([1, 2, 3])
ds = pd.Series(None, index=my_index)
ds.iloc[0] = "a"

FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise an error in a future version of pandas. Value 'a' has dtype incompatible with float64, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
```

I find it hard to follow why `pd.Series(None)` would infer `float` (fine by me), but then prohibit me from assigning "anything" to `None`.

How to set up the Series properly? Especially if you don't know/want to specify the type just yet? The proposed solution should allow to assign any data type later (e.g., `int` or `float` or `str`) without raising an error, as long as the entire series is of the same type, and the initialized series is just empty.

Comment: My first impulse was to try the Any type from python typing. but that does not work.

Comment: Makes sense. If you could specify "any", then the warning itself would be obsolete. It really only makes sense if it enfores an unambiguous pandas type (e.g., the good old `float64`, `Int32`, or what not). Which is precisely what prevents me from initalizing "empty"/`None`

Comment: @error using `typing.Any` would not make sense here, it isn't a `dtype`

Comment: a series has a dtype. "Any" is not really a dtype, perhaps you mean `object`, it isn't clear. What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish here? How are you planning on using this `pd.Series`? That should tell you what dtype you should choose, and you should choose it explicitly when you create the series

Comment: @KingOtto it doesn't make sense because there is no dtype that would correspond to `typing.Any`, which isn't really even a type to begin with, let alone a dtype

Comment: Fundamentally, I think creating a `pd.Series` "if you don't know/want to specify the type just yet?" is just a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: I fundamentally disagree with this comment. Not only is it a very distinct strength of Python itself that types don't need to be declared, it's also the way that Pandas has functioned forever. Types don't *have* to be declared for variables to work - period. But just to get your imagination flowing: say I want to populate an integer series that may or may not hold NaN, and only later decide whether to go for `Int32` or `int`. Doesn't sound so fundamentally bad to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the object as dtype when creating the series.

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Any
from datetime import datetime

my_index = pd.Index([1, 2, 3])
ds = pd.Series(None, index=my_index, dtype=object)
ds.iloc[0] = "a"
ds.iloc[1] = 1
ds.iloc[2] = datetime.now()
```

resulting in this:

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2024-02-15 19:47:53.346932 |

this allows for any python object to be a valid data type. This is also referenced in the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dtypes).

My first instinct was to use Any from typing. But that cannot be interpreted by pandas.

Comment: while this solves the problem, I would argue that it is misguided. `dtype=object` should be avoided. it is there to allow for strings, but it was always a bad solution to the problem of numpy not supporting an adequate string type. On modern pandas, you should use `pd.StringDtype()` if you are going to work with strings, or perhaps even better, use a `pyarrow` backed dataframe and use `"string[pyarrow]"`. While this solves the problem of initializing a pd.Series without know what type of data you want to use with it ahead of time, that is something that you probably shouldn't do to begin with

Comment: I interpreted the question as how to have a mixed dtype series; this would be the only way to do so. I personally don't think it is very advisable to have a mixed dtype series, but that is another issue.

Comment: I don't completely disagree with that, and I also don't completely agree with it. Pandas documentation itself says: Finally, arbitrary objects may be stored using the 'object' dtype, but should be avoided to the extent possible (for performance and interoperability with others). It should be avoided on that we agree, but it is not solely there for the legacy way of having string datatypes inside pandas series/dataframe columns.

Comment: I will add some cautionary statements to my answer to further clarify when I have the time

Comment: For reference, I am linking the associated discussion with the pandas team on this issue (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/57437), which led to exactly this very conclusion: While it is cumbersome to set the very non-ideal dtype `object`, there is no other way to have an "empty" pandas series,

Answer (score -1):

Use the `object` keyword as:

```
my_index = pd.Index([1, 2, 3])
ds = pd.Series(object, index=my_index)
ds.iloc[0] = "a"
ds.iloc[1] = 2


'''
>>> ds
1      a
2      2
3    NaN
dtype: object
'''
```